# CSS 3D cube perspective when rotating

Tags: css, 3d

I'm trying to create a 3D cube with css3, and I've got the cube but it only looks right (like a cube) from one angle:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALKMM.jpg

I've uploaded the code to JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Fb3Uj/

Anybody who can help?

Thanks in advance

```
/* 3D Cube */
#container{
position: absolute;
margin: 120px;
width: 30%;
height:280px;
border:1px dashed red;
-webkit-perspective:600px;
perspective:600px;
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
transform: rotateX(30deg);
/* perspective-origin: 50% 600px; */
}

.cubepart{
position: absolute;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
border:2px solid black;
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
transform-style:preserve-3d;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-backface-visibility:none;
backface-visibility:none;
}

#front{
background: slategrey;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

Comment: Neither looks "right" to me. What do you want it to look like? A perfect square? What are you asking?

Comment: When i rotate it 180deg for example to have the 'front' appear as small as the 'back' looks now, and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Fb3Uj/2/

I've updated your jsfiddle to show what your code should look like.

You should have another DIV containing just the cube beyond the container.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="cube">
        <div class="cubepart" id="front">front</div>
        <div class="cubepart" id="back">back</div>
        <div class="cubepart" id="left">left</div>
        <div class="cubepart" id="right">right</div>
        <div class="cubepart" id="top">top</div>
        <div class="cubepart" id="bottom">bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you can place the perspective on the container and the transform on the cube.

```
#container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
     -moz-perspective: 1000px;
       -o-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for anyone else that's having problems, perpective on the container but rotate the cube, not the container.